# Pex: list with non-null elements

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pex, pex-and-moles

I have a class that is basically a List with a fancy name (`dyn_string`).
I would like to generate test cases with Pex.

To teach Pex how to properly create a `dyn_string` I created this factory:

```
#!cs
[PexFactoryMethod(typeof(dyn_string))]
public static dyn_string CreateDynString(List<string> list)
{
    PexAssume.AreElementsNotNull<string>(list);
    return new dyn_string(list);
}
```

However, I receive the following message:

```
2015-08-18 07:28:50Z>could not generate any test in 2 runs
could not create an instance of Transformation.datatypes.dyn_string
```

Shortly before the a time-out (although I increased the time-out to a higher limit).

Has anybody a suggestion on how to specify that the list should not contain null strings?

EDIT:
I played around a little bit, when I specify the `PexAssume.AreElementsNotNull` in the Parameterized Unit Test (and cast the `dyn_string` to a List) then it works fine, however this means I have to specify this everytime I use a `dyn_string` in a PUT, rather than once in a factory.

Comment: Are there warnings that you need to instrument something? Also, maybe List<string> has worse support than string[].

Comment: I did not find any warnings. I guess List<string> does have less support, however, I am unsure how to work around this.